# determinate progress bar combined with loader animation

Tags: android, android-layout

How to set  determinate progress bar combined with loader animation like this (I need Loader in animated) any idea

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at source code of this kind of library:

- https://github.com/jpardogo/GoogleProgressBar
- https://github.com/DreaminginCodeZH/MaterialProgressBar
- https://github.com/FireZenk/FireZenk-s-ProgressBar

Comment: Thanks for your answer laurent.i need inermiante progress bar with particular Range of progress..How to achieve this on android.i have tried lot of libraries but stil i am not get